# How to implement a button on a website that allows user to save generated array data as ASCII file

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a website with physics simulation tutorials. One of this, generates data and plots it on a canvas element. Tough it is possible to save the image from the canvas as .png I would like the user could be provided with the possibility to download generated data as well. This is not a question regarding downloading existing files an a server. Rather the aim here is to dump some 2d-array data  into a file (in csv format) that the user can download on the push of a button which opens a 'Save as' dialog box.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using HTML5/Javascript to generate and save a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897619/using-html5-javascript-to-generate-and-save-a-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the browser the client is using, a simple [a.download](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Downloading-resources-in-HTML5-a-download) with [Blob URLs](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/#toc-inlineworkers-bloburis) could do.
If you target more browsers, I'd adwise the use of something like [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) to get multi browser support (Here is a [demo](http://eligrey.com/demos/FileSaver.js/)).